# problem with modbus protocol using java programming

Tags: java, tcp, controller, modbus

I have a problem while using the Modbus protocol, to be honest, this my first time dealing with this kind of protocol especially that I am using it to contact a very rare documentation controller(BF-1010).
the connection is true but we can't read the inputs, and I don't know why ??? we are using the library easymodbus and as a technology, we are using java.
you will find bellow the code that we are using and some images for the configuration and results brows the 4 links .

```
[modbus config ][1]
[bf-1010 intrerface][2]
[java program][3]
[results][4]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFa9B.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJpxJ.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZwPN.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ4Td.jpg



package BF;
import de.re.easymodbus.modbusclient.*;
import de.re.easymodbus.exceptions.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import de.re.easymodbus.exceptions.ModbusException;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class connectBF {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception


ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("192.168.9.124",50002);
modbusClient.Connect();
boolean d=modbusClient.isConnected();
System.out.println(d);

try
{
boolean[] input = modbusClient.ReadDiscreteInputs(10020, 2000);

for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
{
if(input[i] == true)  System.out.println("INPUT "+i+" : "+input[i]);
}
}

catch (Exception e)
{
System.out.println("error");
}  

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The table at the bottom of the [modbus config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFa9B.jpg) link is helpful in translating the table above and lays out the call to retrieve DI1-12 (which I believe is what you are trying to do):

Function Code: 2 - Read Discrete Inputs
Starting Address 0x14 - 20 decimal
Quantity of Inputs 0x0C - 12 decimal

So try `modbusClient.ReadDiscreteInputs(20, 12);`.

(you may be trying to retrieve additional fields not covered in the one image; however I'd suggest trying the above first and then extending it to cover additional inputs when you know it works).

A lot of Modbus documentation follows older "standards" and can be quite confusing (see the section "Modbus: When 40001 Really Means 1, or 0 Really Means 1" in [this article](https://www.csimn.com/CSI_pages/Modbus101.html) for more info)